# Chrome bug when rendering table with zoom

Tags: html, google-chrome, zooming

My minimum working example code is pretty straightforward:

```
<body>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 50px; ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25px;" headerindex="0">
                    <div>00</div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25px;" headerindex="1">
                    <div>15</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
```

Please open the following JSfiddle in Chrome at 100% zoom: https://jsfiddle.net/kghq1hs2/

Check the width of any "td" element. It should be 25px.

Now zoom to 110%, 125% or anything similar.

Check again the width of any "td" element, and find that it is *not* 25px, but something like 24.667px, 24.800px... or 25.200px, 25.333px, ..., depending on which td you chose.

If you have more than two columns, you can see a pattern: the first half of the tds are rendered too big, and the second half are rendered too small, which accumulates if you have like 100 of these cells and makes for very odd-looking cell borders if you expect them to take up exactly 25px each.

This does not happen in Internet Explorer. I could circumvent it by using a width that happens to be divisible through 10 and 3 and 4, e.g. 60. But 60 is too wide.

Any suggestions on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not occur in Gecko- or Trident-based browsers. However, as per the Chromium dev team, this seems to be "working as intended" in Chrome, at least the bug has status WONTFIX: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=717469

Feel free to leave a comment in the bug report if you think that they should fix this.

Comment: NOTE: it's because their tables don't support decimal width values in px for cells, if you check you'll see that those weird dimensions when zoomed are calculated so that when you multiply by the zoom factor you fall back to an integer value. That's probably why they say it's "working as intended", they made it probably because it's much more work to make the tables support decimal values.. lazy

Answer (score -1):

The one thing i learned is that if you want something responsive you want to use %. If i use a width of 1 % it alwase gives me 24px

so change every td you have with the width of 25px to 1% and you will alwase have 24px.

Also its better go give the td a class and use CSS it is cleaner that way.

I hope this helped

Cees